How can I force a specific sequence of memory stores in standard C++?
In a typical embedded system or device driver, it’s often necessary to make a very specific sequence of memory stores to MMIO/PIO registers. As an example:
store byte 0x10 to 0x40002000
store byte 0xAA to 0x40002001

It would not be correct, for example, to combine the writes (e.g., write the 16-bit quantity 0xAA10 to 0x40002000) nor to optimize the writes out if they are never read.
Usually in C, we would use volatile variables for this purpose:
*(volatile uint8_t *)0x40002000 = 0x10;
*(volatile uint8_t *)0x40002001 = 0xAA;

In standard C++, is code like this guaranteed to result in the desired sequence of stores? If not, is there a way to guarantee such a sequence?
What are the corresponding parts in the standard (any version)? If this is not possible (or not well-defined), please back that up with the standard.
This is a bit of a language-lawyer question.

AFAIK, the standard has not much to say about volatile variables except that reads and writes to them are considered as "side effects". That means that they cannot be removed and the order must be preserved. But except for that you are at the mercy of the implementation (compiler and environment). These generally "do what you mean" with volatile variables, otherwise, they would not be very useful.

volatile only guarantees that the read or write is not optimized away. It also promises to keep order of events on a single object. There's no guarantee on the relative order for multiple distinct objects, unless the results of reading one is proved to affect another. But in the embedded world, compilers are created with the embedded demands in mind; thus they're more strict about volatile. There's this std::atomic class too; but it has higher demands, and uses bus locking opcodes, if available.

The language standard doesn't say much about hardware registers. On the other hand, a compiler that lets you write to those addresses will better handle this "correctly". Otherwise they will quickly get out of business.

If embedded world had tried to use C++ sooner, and had made contact with ISO committee, we would have had better rules in that regard. I hope MC producers introduce their voting members soon.

No, but have a look at the compiler atomic builtins (gcc: __atomic_store_n()) and its memory orders. The memory orders can prevent command reordering by the CPU (e.g. by out-of-order-execution). Additionally, you have prevent reordering by the compiler by using asm volatile("": : :"memory").

@Red.Wave Using std::atomic for accessing machine memory registers needs unclean address casting. I would additionally use static_assert to check if the size of the used std::atomic<> type is the same as the accessed hardware register.

It's spelled std::atomic_ref.

volatile has the same exact meaning in c++ as in c.  and the guarantees are the same.  Especially for embedded programming.  As in c, since this kind of code is not re-entrant, and will not tolerate other access to the target hardware, either disable interrupts or use any other sensible means to guard the code.  atomic functionality is only needed if your processor has multiple cores, and access to the hardware is done in more than one thread.  Besides that, any other fences, etc...  depend on your processor and will thus have the exact same requirements for c and c++.

You can achieve the guaranteed writing order by using C++20's std::atomic_ref<>, as proposed by 'Passer By'. This code uses the memory order std::memory_order::seq_cst.
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>

void demo()
{
    std::atomic_ref<uint8_t> reg1(*reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0x40002000));
    std::atomic_ref<uint8_t> reg2(*reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(0x40002001));

    reg1.store(0x10);
    reg2.store(0xaa);
}

See the generated code in Compiler Explorer.

atomic_ref does not guarantee that the writes aren't combined and it also doesn't guarantee that they aren't optimized away (e.g. if another store to the second register follows). I don't think any compiler actually performs such optimizations, but they are allowed to.

I guess it should be std::atomic_ref<volatile uint8_t> to make the required guarantee, but that currently doesn't behave as expected because it doesn't provide the integer operations and I am also not sure that the combined volatile/atomic behavior is actually properly specified for this.

All volatile does is tell the compiler that the value at the address in question may be changed by an external agent. This will ensure that the compiler will generate LDR and STR instructions every time access is required and thus prevents the read or write being optimized away.
The actual ordering of reads and writes however is something that is processor-dependent and often determined by the CPU architecture in question. ARM is notoriously out-of-order. To guarantee ordering, the compiler will need to add memory barriers like DMB on ARM. Volatile does not do this.
Disabling caching for the given addresses may help. Otherwise, it will need to manually flush the cache for each and every write.

You are right, but the original question was, how to do this in standard C++. std::atomic/_ref with the right memory order does generate out-of-order-capable barriers, However, I think that using std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order::seq_cst) between the volatile accesses may be sufficient.


In standard C++, is code like this guaranteed to result in the desired sequence of stores?

Yes, because of the as-if rule as described in a wiki article:

Accesses (reads and writes) to volatile objects occur strictly according to the semantics of the expressions in which they occur. In particular, they are not reordered with respect to other volatile accesses on the same thread.

The standardeeze version is found in [intro.abstract] 4.1.2 which speaks in terms of the observable behavior of the program:


The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
(6.1)
Accesses through volatile glvalues are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
(6.2)
At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to one of the possible results that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
(6.3)
The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place in such a fashion that prompting output is actually delivered before a program waits for input. What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.
These collectively are referred to as the observable behavior of the program.
[Note 2: More stringent correspondences between abstract and actual semantics can be defined by each implementation. — end note]


Note:
The as-if rule is not a formal name, but it is short for what is described in a footnote in the above mentioned [intro.abstract] chapter:

4.1.2.1. ... conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below5



This provision is sometimes called the “as-if” rule, because an implementation is free to disregard any requirement of this document as long as the result is as if the requirement had been obeyed, as far as can be determined from the observable behavior of the program. For instance, an actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no side effects affecting the observable behavior of the program are produced.


